# Paypal pro API and validation error while payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm using Paypal Pro API (not the hosted payments) to process my website payments. It works fine with some credit cards and I'm able to finish the payment but for `mastercard` type I get following error from API:

Value is invalid (must be visa, mastercard, amex or discover)

Please note that I'm using `mastercard` but still I get that error. Is there any configuration or options in Paypal control panel to enable or disable accepted cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value needs to be `MasterCard` as opposed to `mastercard`.  It is case sensitive.

Comment: Sorry didn't get that right. is there any parameters in API to pass the type of credit card?

Comment: Well, in your question you mentioned "PayPal Pro" which uses the Classic API, but now I just realized you had this tagged with paypal-rest-sdk, which is different.  Credit cards in rest don't require PayPal Pro, and again, it's a different API.  If you are using Pro then you'll need the classic DoDirectPayment API, and then yes, it includes a CREDITCARDTYPE parameter in the request.